# How to Set Xcode 4 Toolbar Show Icon Only?

Tags: toolbar, xcode

In Xcode 4, I can't right click the toolbar to customize it to show icon only or text only. I also can't find any options in the main menu to change it. However, I do see screenshots of Xcode 4 with icon only toolbar somewhere. Any idea?

This is a screenshot from [Xcode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/NewProject/NewProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH2-SW5):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Command-click on the oval button in the upper-right corner of the titlebar to toggle text-under-icons.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't save space, and the icons aren't available as smaller versions either.

Comment: But it's still nice if you're one of those people who doesn't like text beneath your toolbar icons.